# What formula would allow me to lookup the value given that it is the first instance that it is not blank?

Tags: indexing, lookup, xlookup

Basically, this is my table:

|  | Jan-23 | Feb-23 | Mar-23 | Apr-23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC |  | 1 |  |  |
| DEF | 1 |  |  |  |
| GHI |  | 1 |  | 1 |

On another sheet I have those set codes listed vertically:

```
ABC, DEF, GHI
```

I would like to have a formula where it would provide me with the first date there is a value in:

```
ABC 2/2023
DEF 1/2023
GHI 4/2023
```

I have tried this formula
`=IFERROR(INDEX('Set Plan'!$P$3:$AY$3, XLOOKUP(1, ('Set Plan'!$P4:$AY282 > 0) * ('Set Plan'!$C$4:$C$282 = $J925), 'Set Plan'!$P$3:$AY$3, "", 0, 1)), "No Match Found")` but no luck

Comment: Is the Image You added your `table`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this to get the desired result

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Set Plan'!$P$3:$AY$3, XLOOKUP(1, ('Set Plan'!$P4:$AY282 > 0) * ('Set Plan'!$C$4:$C$282 = $J925), 'Set Plan'!$P$3:$AY$3, "", 0, 1), "No Match Found")
```

Please do look at the cell addresses that I am using in the formula and ensure the source and destination cell addresses are correct, when using the formula.